# PTR records not been created and/or updated

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, internal-dns, reverse-dns

Windows domain, domain and forest functional levels at Windows Server 2003. Windows 2003 and 2008R2 domain controllers. Same for DNS (AD integrated). Dynamic updates on DNS zones are set to "Secure Only". DHCP running on Linux, it is not set the update DNS, clients do.

I am experiencing a weird behavior. If I manually create an A record, a corresponding PTR is properly created. If a client registers an A record, a PTR is not been created, or updated. Even if I go to the client created A record, un-check the "Update associated pointer (PTR) record", apply, check it back, apply and OK. Still, the PTR record is not created.

Further information that might be relevant. I have two DNS running on Windows server 2003 and one running on Windows server 2008R2. Once again, zones are AD integrated.

This is how the reverse lookup zones look under dnsmgmt on the Windows 2003 servers:

[image]

This is how they look on the Windows 2008 server:

[image]

Is there a well known operation problem with having mixed DNS servers (2003 and 2008)? This is driving me crazy, as all PTR were been updated fine until very recently. As a matter of fact, some clients are still successfully updating the PTR, while the majority is not.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I've seen this. When using DHCP, by default (some/most/all) Windows OS's expect the DHCP server to register the DNS name. If your DHCP server is not doing that, do the following on the client so it will make its own DNS registrations.
Control Panel, Network Adapter, TCP, Properties, Advanced, DNS
Enable checkbox: Register this connection's addresses in DNS
Invoke cmd "ipconfig /registerdns"

Comment: "DHCP running on Linux, it is not set the update DNS, clients do."  -- Clients are already configured to do this. It has been working fine until now. The behavior is sporadic.

Comment: Are you getting and DNSApi events on the client? I still sometimes see and event #11187 PTR, 11191 A, on some of my clients. Despite them being properly configured it sends the DNS registration request to 10.1.1.1, which is not one of our DNS servers. Event begins like this: The system failed to update and remove pointer (PTR) resource records (RRs) for network adapter
with settings: